# Prevent code commits to Azure Git repos with specific keywords

Tags: git

I have a Azure Git Repos where angular based code is managed. I want to prevent code commits to the repository containing keywords like debugger.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: That's not how Git works. You could implement a pre-commit hook, but that is something that would have to be configured on every developer's workstation and is trivial to circumvent. What is your actual objective? Why do you want to prevent this? Why can't you use pull requests to enforce proper code review?

Comment: Thanks @DanielMann for your response. We do have PRs which perform code review before moving it to Build and Release process. I wanted to know is there any out-of-box option available to deal with it

Comment: Nothing out of the box that I know of, but Azure devops has the ability to add custom branch polocies, and you might be able to find an out of the box solution for those https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pr-status-policy?view=azure-devops I remember this is quite involved though, needing setting up an external tool.